# MVVM Design Consideration

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, viewmodel

I am currently developing a new WPF application and have the majority of my business logic layer developed (ie my Models).

I am about implement ViewModel classes to represent one feature of my application. I am quite new to the Model-View-ViewModel pattern and I have a question about which approach would be best to use when implementing my ViewModel classes.

From examples online I have been finding that often the Model is a member of the ViewModel. Using this approach, the ViewModel exposes the properties of the Model-member so that they can be bound to the Model in the View.

For example:

```
Public Class MyViewModel
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

  Private _myModel As ModelClass

  Public Property MyModelPropertyA As Object
    Get
      Return _myModel.MyModelPropertyA
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
      _myModel.MyModelPropertyA = value
      RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyModelPropertyA")
    End Set
  Public Property MyModelPropertyB As Object
    Get
      Return _myModel.MyModelPropertyB
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
      _myModel.MyModelPropertyB = value
      RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyModelPropertyB")
    End Set
    '.... And so On'

End Class
```

What I don't like about this approach is the fact that there are a lot of properties that I will be re-writing.

So, I am considering the option of Inheriting the model class in the ViewModel instead of using a private member.

Like So:

```
Public Class MyViewModel
      Inherits MyModel
      Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

      Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

      'Now all of my properties are inherited'
End Class
```

The problem with the second approach is that I'm not sure how to convert my models into view models while the application is running.

You can't set viewModelInstance = ModelInstance.

(But you can set modelInstance = viewModelInstance)

I'm looking for advice on the best approach on how to implement the ViewModel classes.

Comment: Your use of inheritance is interesting.  Regarding your last question, you'd need a factory which hides the object creation.  One problem I see, though, is if a Model object appears on two different Views, and thus has two different View Models.  If it's already instantiated as VmA then you can't turn into into VmB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not even think about inheriting your viewModel from model - this will be a hack which nobody will like. If you are too lazy too expose all the properties (BTW resharper can do it automatically) then you can include your model into your viewModel and provide an access to it via some readonly property. But you should still have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented in model class.

Some code (sorry for C#):

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // this raises PropertyChanged
}

class ViewModel
{
    private readonly Model _model;

    public Model Model { get { return _model; } }
}
```

View XAML:

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding Model.Name}" />
```

Comment: It's not a matter of being lazy. It's a matter of meeting a tight deadline. If inheritance is not the best approach, and you believe it to be a "hack", then please explain why.

Comment: @Frinavale - inheritance might work in your case, but I would recomment adding model as property. Several disadvantages I see in this kind of inheritance: **a)** First of all - for me it is confusing relation between M and VM at all. Like basic OOP books say that Dog inherits from Animal because Dog is some specific animal but none of them states that Dog should inherit from Head because both of them have nose, eyes and ears. **b)** Your VM receives functionality your model had (not sure whether you have any), but imagine you had some persistence logic in Model, do you want to persist VMs?

Comment: **c)** you won't be able (at least without multiple inheritance) to inherit your VM from something else. My VMs are usually inherited from something like `ViewModelBase` and some of them might be inherited from smth like `EntityEditorViewModelBase`. You're restricting yourself by inheriting from Model. **d)** You won't be able to parameterize you VM with your model in one(!) line of code, instead you will have to copy all the properties (hopefully you will not forget any property?)

Comment: Thank you very very much for taking the time to explain this to me. I have already started to redo my VMs to use properties instead of inheritance.

Comment: The approach that Snowbear is recommending was first written about (I think) in my article at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF-Presentation-Models.aspx . But Frinavale's use of inheritance is interesting, and as for Snowbear's argument against it: (a) inheritance is mainly about interface inheritance, not about dogs being animals, and (b) your Model should never contain persistence logic (that's what the Data Access layer is for). As for the limitation in (c), you can always do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb625996.aspx.

Comment: @HappyNomad, (a) - he was going to inherit Model, so it was definetely a dog. (b) Say this to CSLA users, Unit of work IMO also somewhere around. I think all those guys will disagree with you. Personally I also do not have anything related to persistence in models (honesly my models usually do not have any logic, and also because of that I have something more useful to inherit VMs from).

Answer (score 1):

The ViewModel typically wraps/encapsulates logic relational to the View. Using a ViewModel to simply pass through the Model data is un-needed IMHO. While a purist approach would be to define a ViewModel and pass this data through; under certain circumstances this is simply not needed as the application is simplistic in nature. If the application has *any* growth potential then using a ViewModel would be necessary.

If you had a `Person` Model; the ViewModel may typically contain a property which exposes an  `ObservableCollection<Person>` called `People`. The ViewModel is the orchestrator for the View; not a pass through for the Model.

You should however not tie your Model to the ViewModel for reasons mentioned above as they should be decoupled from each other in both theory and practice.

Comment: The application will need to be able to grow. However, there are some complicated relationships between properties within my model that I found it difficult to accurately achieve using Converters and views only. I decided that the best approach would be to create View Models for my models.

Comment: @Frinavale "... would be to create View Models for my models..." ViewModels and Models are not 1:1. ViewModels have a relation typically of 1:1 with the View. You do not need a ViewModel for each Model; create a single ViewModel which can take care of prepping the varying model data for the View

Answer (score 1):

Check out this diagram taken from [here](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mvvm/wpf-line-of-business-introduction/).

[image]

This is an excellent diagram to refer to in order to ensure you are following the pattern correctly.  As you can see there are various ways to interact between the layers, but the main thing is that seperation.  Always ensure that each layer only knows about it's parent layer and not it's children, i.e. VM knows about the Model, but not the view, and the Model knows about the Business layer and not the view model or view.

As you can see from the arrows (and as others mentioned) the Model can be 'exposed through a single property on the viewmodel', which means the view then has a direct link to the model via this, or the Model can be 'Abstracted or re-implemented in Model properties' on the vm.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, when i talk about the "parent layer and it's children" I don't mean this in an oo hierarchical manner.  I just tend to think of them in a hierachy way like Model being at the top, VM underneath and then at the bottom is the view.  They can each look up but not down the hierachy.